# What is "compute to control node" in Azure SQL DW Query plan?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-synapse

What exactly is "Compute to Control Node" step in Azure SQL DW Query execution plan? Does that mean ADW is moving the data to control node and then performing the JOIN. I understand Shuffle operation which redistributes data among the compute nodes. But I did not get in what situation does the data flow from Compute to Control node for a JOIN.

All 3 high cost operations in screenshot are associated with moving 2 Fact tables and the biggest dimension tables.

[Query_Plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fbmOY.jpg)
Thanks

Comment: Was it just a simple, two-table join? Data can move from the compute nodes to the control node when sorts and aggregations are being performed, but I don't think a simple "select * from a inner join b" type of query would cause this condition. Tell us more about the tables and query.

Comment: It is a LEFT Join between couple of fact tables and their associated dimensions. Both fact tables are hash distributed on the same column and also joined on same column. But the dimensions are Round robin distributed, I thought of Replicating the dimensions but looks like that feature is still in preview. I will post the Query and screenshot from the plan shortly.

Comment: Added the query plan

Comment: As much as the graphical plan simplifies understanding the costs of the query, the XML explain plan is much more rich. If you look at the XML, find dsql_operations where distribution='Control'. The following node will be something like 'PARTITION_MOVE' or 'TRIM_MOVE', which will tell you the precise reason for the movement to the control node, and the data being moved.

Comment: Please share the explain plan or review it yourself to see what type of move it is. Could be just the results sent back to the control node for return to client.

Answer (score 1):

You can have portions of a query sent to the control node in operations such as PartitionMoves. For example, this might occur when you do a GroupBy on a column that's not a distribution column and the optimizer thinks the result set is small enough to send up to the control node for final aggregations.

Comment: I do not have any GroupBy in the query. It is a LEFT Join between couple of fact tables and their associated dimensions. Both fact tables are hash distributed on the same column and also joined on same column. But the dimensions are Round robin distributed, I thought of Replicating the dimensions but looks like that feature is still in preview. I will post the Query and screenshot from the plan shortly.

Comment: If you have more than two tables involved, which it appears you do from the later mention of dimensions, it is a little misleading to think of this as a join between two tables. Rather, think of it as a wholistic strategy for querying 5 or 6 tables in a join.